# Как создаются такие элементы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не знаю насколько корректен такой вопрос тут, но все же попытаю удачу.
Верстаю сайт по макету и на макете столкнулся с такими элементами, хочу спросить с помощью чего они создаются.
На макете в фигме первый и второй элемент это просто векторы, как такое создается в браузере?
На счет третьего элемента просто не уверен, на сколько я понимаю это просто элемент с свойством position: absolute; так-ли это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также если это может понадобиться, предоставляю ссылку на макет: 

https://www.figma.com/community/file/1111919284446759426

Comment: Основной слой `position:relative`, внутри картинка как есть (тоже relative по сути), остальные элементы `position: absolute` с `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom`. много точек - это или svg выдирается и вставляется как фон (можно в base64 конвертнуть и в css `background: ...`, чтобы не вставлять в html кусок). 3 блок просто верстается, 1 - тоже просто класс... В целом, простая верстка тут у Вас

Comment: Первый раз по макету верстаю, вот и столкнулся с такими трудностями. Как сделать примерно представлял, а какой из всех вариантов в голове будет правильным и корректным не знал, поэтому спросил тут. Когда знаешь как именно делать, тогда верстка действительно простая)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar еще такой вопрос возник, такие кружки создаются просто div'ками?

Comment: Ну самый просто вариант дивами. Можно к какому-то элементу через `:before` и `:after` докинуть – будет то же самое, но это уже вкусовщина